# Searching through 100 directories 10 at a time for a files that are of a specific year?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with about 100 subdirectories that have 5TB of data. I want to collect all data in the year 2016. So as to not strain the server, I would like to search through 10 directories at a time with a maxdepth of 3. Is there a way to search through these directories blocks of 10 at a time?

I have run the following code on my own computer, it outputs garbage data also, I am thinking of nesting a do loop on top of this loop to restrict search through 10 at a time, but I am not sure how it would go.

```
for d in $(ls /path/to/directory)
do
        find $d -maxdepth 3 -type d -newermt 2016-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31
        echo $d
done > /path/to/file
```

`/path/to/directory` is the directory that nests all the 100 subdirectories.

Output will be a list of names sent to a text file, with the directories created in 2016.

Comment: `find` is fairly efficient. Just use `find /path/to/dir -type d -newermt 2015-12-31 ! -newermt 2017-01-01` and not worry about limiting to a maxdepth of 3. If you wanted to include time as well, you could use, e.g. `-newermt "2015-12-31 23:59:59"`

Comment: Hi David, I really appreciate the quick response. Do you think searching through all the directories won't slow down the server? For curiosity sake, is there a way to loop through 10 directories at a time?

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, you can look through multiple directories in one go with `find /pathA /pathB /pathC -newer...`

Comment: Your server will be fine. `find` will only be a single process out of MANY running and your server is more than capable of handling the additional `find` (even if it is a 100 directory deep `find`). You can always check current CPU utilization by running the `top` command if you are curious.

Comment: Mark, I actually did not know that! Thanks, this is really helpful

Comment: David, thanks for the info, i'll definitely check it out using top

Comment: Remember your utilization is based on the number of *Cores*. So if you have 8-cores, `800%` is full utilization. If you see `100%` and you have 8-cores, you are utilizing 1/8 of your CPU capacity.

Comment: @camteam100 Since I glean you are worried about using CPU on the server, you can also `renice` your find command to run at a lower scheduling priority yielding to the currently running processes. You can increase the *"nice"* value of your program from 1-19 (0 is default, 19 is run only when nothing else on the system wants to). Adding 2-5 is more than enough. So you can background your `find` command, grab its PID and then `renice` it, e.g. `find ... & ; myfindpid=$!; renice +2 $myfindpid` That will minimize any impact of your find command even on a fully-utilized server.

Comment: @David, this actually is the solution. Thanks for letting me know of renice option. I will try it out when I am running the find command

Comment: You might want to also `ionice` the process.

Comment: Also, when you are iterating over a set of files with `for` don't use `ls` - just use `for /path/to/directory/*/` - the final slash makes it only consider directories and omit files. It's not recursive, while `find` is by default.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, by using /path/to/directory/*/ do I still need to define -type d in the find command?

Comment: In this case, probably yes - if all you want to find is directories. The `for` statement is just selecting the directories to start the `find` from - it has no effect on what the results of the `find` are. By the way, you should always quote variables when you are using their values: `find "$d" ...`